# Issue with grails fixtures and domain class validation

Tags: grails, fixtures

I am new to fixtures in grails and have bumped into this problem in my code.  I am trying to use fixtures to build an instance of the following domain objects:

```
class Tree {
    static constraints = {
        relationships(
            validator: { relationships, tree->
                relationships && 
                !(relationships.isEmpty()) && 
                relationships.every { it.validate() 
            }
        )
    }
    static hasMany = [
        relationships: Branch
    ]
}

class Branch {
    Tree tree
    static constraints = {}
}
```

I have tried these implementations, all of which result in a validation error:

```
fixture {
    Build {
        //oak(Tree)
        //oakBranch(Branch){ tree = oak }

        //oakBranch(Branch){ tree = ref("oak") }
        //oak(Tree)

        //oak(Tree){ relationships = [ ref("oakBranch") ] }
        //oakBranch(Branch)
    }
}
```

All implementations return the same error: "on field of 'relationships': rejected value [null]".  Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your custom validator by checking for `relationships && !(relationships?.isEmpty()) &&` however, if you remove it and re-write your code as follow you can bypass your error :

```
class Tree {
    static constraints = {
        relationships (
                validator: { relationships, tree->
//                    relationships &&
//                            !(relationships?.isEmpty()) &&
                            relationships.every { it.validate()}
                }
        )
    }
    static hasMany = [relationships: Branch]
}
```

fixture.groovy:

```
import tree.*
fixture {
    Build {
        oak(Tree)  {  }
        oakBranch(Branch){ tree = oak }

        //oakBranch(Branch){ tree = ref("oak") }
        //oak(Tree)

        //oak(Tree){ relationships = [ ref("oakBranch") ] }
        //oakBranch(Branch)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The example I have provided is a stripped down version of the original, of which Tree's validator must check that relationships is not null, it is a list that is not empty, and all relationships pass their own validation.  Although your response  does work, these validations cannot be removed.

Comment: When you are loading the fixture is there any data in the tables? Meaning is there any relationship there?

Comment: I am currently loading the fixture in a test. I assume that there shouldn't be any data in the tables.